# plotting "with impulses" using multiple fields from an input file

Tags: gnuplot

sample "input file":

```
x  y1(red)  y2(blue)  y3(green)
10  0.08      0.02      0.90
15  0.03      0.90      0.07
20  0.85      0.10      0.05
```

My x-axis is 10, 15, 20, or column 1 in the sample input file. Columns 2-4 are my dependent variables, labeled by color. The x-axis is distance; the y-axis is impulse signal.

## goal

I would like a graph plotted as "x:y with impulse", or something equivalent. My output would appear like:

```
 x =     10   15   20
green   0.90 0.07 0.05
red     0.08 0.03 0.85
blue    0.02 0.90 0.10
```

At x = 10, I would see a **green** line with an intensity of 0.90, overlapped by a **red** line with an intensity of 0.08, followed by a **blue** line with intensity 0.02. I can tell at a glance that for x=10, my parameter is 90% green, 8% red, and 2% blue.

For x=15, I would have a **blue** line with an intensity of 0.90, a **green** line with an intensity of 0.07, and a **red** line with intensity 0.03.

and similar for x = 20.

In other words, **my goal** is to see, for a given x-value, exactly what percentage contributions my three dependent variables have.

## problem

Currently, I can do something like

```
plot "input file" u 1:4 w i lc rgb "green"
replot "input file" u 1:3 w i lc rgb "blue"
replot "input file" u 1:2 w i lc rgb "red"
```

Unfortunately, the most recent replot will overlap and cover up any previous plots of smaller impulse.

With this approach, my plot would look like:

```
 x =     10   15   20
green   0.90 ---- ----
red     0.08 0.03 0.85
blue    ---- 0.90 ----
```

I would only see green at x = 10, and blue only at x = 15. Because red is replotted last, it overlaps and covers the other colors due to having a greater intensity. I can see red perfectly at all three x-values, but I lose green and blue.

Is there maybe a way to tell replot to not overshadow previous plots? Or an alternative approach to replot to achieve the goal stated above?

#### summary

I am trying to plot a multi-field input at each point x, while preserving the original legend label in my key for each column.

In my actual case, I have anywhere from 8-40 fields, across a few hundred x values, so I can't simply input manually which columns I'd like where.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I am open to any solutions, even a different software if gnuplot cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
  set linetype 1 lc "green"
  set linetype 2 lc "red"
  set linetype 3 lc "blue"
  unset key
  set yrange [0:1]
  set style data histogram
  set style histogram cluster gap 3
  set style fill solid

  plot for [col=2:4] 'inputfile' using col:xticlabel(1)
```

[image]